# How Do I Autoatically Copy Website Address URL

Tags: vba

I'm a journalist.  I spend countless hours copying brief passages from various webpages, and then pasting those passages - along with attribution to the websites I found them - into web-based articles.

For example, many of my articles have passages which look like this:

The Mexican finance minister [wrote](http://www.cnbc.com/2017/02/06/german-finance-minister-agrees-euro-too-low-for-germany.html):

> The euro exchange rate is, strictly speaking, too low for the German economy's competitive position.

I want to use VBA to do the following:

(1) When I highlight the text I want to copy - in the example "The euro exchange rate is, strictly speaking, too low for the German economy's competitive position"

(2) I would also automatically copy the url where the text comes from (in this case, http://www.cnbc.com/2017/02/06/german-finance-minister-agrees-euro-too-low-for-germany.html)

(3) So when I paste the text into my blog, it would automatically paste the text and ALSO the url.  In other words, I would end up with what I wrote above.

I think the write script is IE.LocationURL to automatically determine the url I'm at.  And I know how to launch Internet Explorer and navigate to a web page.

But I don't know how to put the script together.

Here's my attempt:

```
  Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
' Declare Windows API function for setting active window
Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" _
Alias "SetForegroundWindow" (ByVal Hwnd As Long)As Long
' Declare Internet Explorer object
Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Sub Main
   ' create instance of InternetExplorer
   Set IE = New InternetExplorer
   ' using your newly created instance of Internet Explorer
   With IE
      SetForegroundWindow IE.HWND
      .Visible = True
      .Navigate2 "http://www.cnbc.com/2017/02/06/german-finance-minister-agrees-euro-too-low-for-germany.html"

     ' Wait until page we are navigating to is loaded
      Do While .Busy
      Loop
      Do
      Loop Until .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

      On Error Resume Next
         If Err Then
           'Do Nothing
         Else
     'Copy the selected text
        SendKeys "^c"

      ' Here's where I'm trying to copy the url
          debug.print.IE.LocationURL 

          End With

       End If

   ' Tidy Up
   Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

I would then run another script to automatically log into my publishing platform and paste the copied text and url info.  Ideally, it would be pasted in the format shown at the top of this post (with linked text and then indented quote).

But if I just have the copied text and url, that would still save me a lot of time.

I use Nuance Dragon Naturally Speaking to run my VBA scripts.

But I'm lost. Please help steer me in the right direction! Thanks!

UPDATE: I guess what I really need is a way to store the url as a string.  I can then later write the string (and just paste the selected text the old-fashioned way, with control-v.)

So does anyone know how to read and store the url as a string or value?

Comment: I think there's a chrome plugin that does just that.

Comment: For instance this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-copy/bijpdibkloghppkbmhcklkogpjaenfkg?hl=en

Comment: David, thank you. Auto Copy worked for a little while, then stopped working.

Comment: It seems I want to use the following:   currenturl = ie.LocationURL.  But I don't know how to build a VBA script around  currenturl = ie.LocationURL to read that string and then paste it into my web story.

Comment: I found the following script which claims to be able to copy the current web page, but it's not working for me (I'm getting all sorts of errors):

Comment: My last comment got cut off, as the script was too long.  Oops, sorry.

Comment: It seems like I'm close here, but can't combine the two strings from clipboard:  Sub Main
Dim clip As String
Dim yourl As String
Dim z As String

SendKeys "^c", 1
clip = Clipboard

Wait .2

SendKeys "^l", 1
SendKeys "^c", 1

yourl = Clipboard

z = "yourl" & "clip"


End Sub

Comment: After struggling with this for days, it seems like the main thing I need is a VBA script which lets me (1) copy the url into the clipboard, and save that as one variable or string and (2) copy the text from the article into the clipboard, and save that as a SECOND variable or string,  and then retrieve and write the two variables/strings where I want.

Answer (score 0):

Playing around with a bunch of possibilities, I think I finally created a script which works.

To do it, I

(1) first have to copy the url manually from the web page by highlighting the url and the copying it to clipboard using control-c on my keyboard;

(2) select (i.e. manually highlight with my keyboard) the text within the article which I want to copy.

Here's the script:

```
Sub Main
    Dim MyData As DataObject
Dim strClip As String

Set MyData = New DataObject
MyData.GetFromClipboard
strClip = MyData.GetText
Wait 5
SendKeys "^c"
'I have code here to open up the webpage where I'm inserting the information

SendKeys "^v"
' The line above pastes the text I have selected

SendKeys strClip
' The line above sends the url which I previously saved

End Sub
```

I don't know if it's the most efficient or elegant solution, but it works.